# How do we guess the recurrence relation from the given equation

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation

In this book [introduction to algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) , i have been reading about a method named substitution method to solve the recurrence, the recurrence equation is 
\begin{equation}
T(n)=2 T(\lfloor n / 2\rfloor)+n
\end{equation}

the author guessed the solution was $O(n \log n)$ and proved it below, my question is how to make the guess? I wanted to know why it cant be $O(n^2)$? How do you guess them correctly at first?

\begin{aligned} T(n) & \leq 2(c\lfloor n / 2\rfloor \lg (\lfloor n / 2\rfloor))+n \\ & \leq c n \lg (n / 2)+n \\ &=c n \lg n-c n \lg 2+n \\ &=c n \lg n-c n+n \\ & \leq c n \lg n \end{aligned}

Comment: @Evil i am sorry, i have corrected the post, please let me know if i need to change any thing in it.

Answer (score 2):

To guess simple recurrences most useful step is to study basic intuition beyond so-called [master theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) that looks at any recursion as if it is implicit tree.

Your case is admissible for it and thus easy: on each step you have half of task (peek one branch down in tree), and $O(n)$ work. Multiply tree height and amount of work on each step and you will get your guess. But you will probably never guess any inadmissible case.

Comment: how do i peek one branch in a tree? the equation is given like 2(⌊/2⌋)+ but from that thing i can only figure out each node gets divided in to two at each step

Comment: @Naveen if any amount of work divided in two on each level, how much levels do you have if total amount is $n$?

Answer (score 1):

The guess $O(n^2)$ also works: 
$$
T(n) \leq 2c\lfloor n/2\rfloor^2 + n \leq \frac{c}{2} n^2 + n \leq cn^2,
$$
as long as $c \geq 2$.

The author did not *guess* the answer. Presumably the author already *knew* the answer.

In practice, for most recurrences you would encounter one of the following methods will work:

- Open up the recurrence (also known as repeated substitution).
- Appeal to a standard result such as the master theorem.
- Use a computer experiment (could be deceiving).

In this case, the recurrence is so well-known and commonplace that the author must have seen it worked out somewhere. It can also be "solved" (i.e., the asymptotic behavior of $T(n)$ determined) using the master theorem, which is how you could do it.